# Connot access to multer req.body when I send multiple images

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I use Multer package for uploading. I have to check token before uploading images. There is no problem with `.single()`. But when I want to upload more than one image, It seems there isn't `req.body.token`.

*** Check token function:**

```
_checkToken = (token) => {
    return User.
    findOne({'token':token},'_id')
    .then((data) => {
        if(data) return data._id.toString()
        else return 'invalid'
    })
}
```

*** Request for _checkToken():**

```
let userId
checkRequest = (data) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        let token = data.token
        if(token){
            _checkToken(token).then((auth) => {

                if(auth.length==24){
                    _userId = mongoose.mongo.ObjectID(auth)
                    resolve('valid')
                }
                else{
                    resolve('invalid')
                }
            }).catch(err => reject('invalid'))
        }
    })
}
```

*** Multer diskStorage**

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        checkRequest(req.body).then((check)=>{
            if(check=='valid'){
                let newPost = new Post()
                newPostId = newPost._id
                let dir = `./data/posts/${newPostId}`;
                if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
                    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
                }
                cb(null, dir)
            }
            else return false
        })
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
})

var uploadImages = multer({ storage: storage }).single('image')
```

*** route**

```
routes.post('/post', (req,res) => {
    uploadImages(req,res,(err)=>{
        if(err) res.send('error')
        else{
            if(newPostId){
                // ...
                let data = {
                    _id: newCampaignId,
                    // ...
                }
                Post.create(data).then((p)=>{
                    res.send('done')
                })
            }
        }
    })
})
```

When I use `.array('images')` instead of `.single('image')` , It seems there isn't `req.body.token` because `_checkToken(token)` returns `invalid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your usage of multer so that it is part of the middleware stack for the desired route. Your current usage of multer only extracts the file information but doesn't process `req.body`.

```
let uploadImages = multer({storage})

routes.post('/post', uploadImages.array('images'), (req,res) => {  
  if(newPostId){
      // ...
      let data = {
          _id: newCampaignId,
          // ...
      }
      Post.create(data).then((p)=>{
          res.send('done')
      })
  }
})
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much. Everything is ok!